# Creating sub transactions inside @Transactional controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-transactions

I have controller annotaded `@Transactional`. Than there are several services for processing request. What I need is to split that transaction to some sub-transactions based on processing logic in those services.

If I also annotate some of those services `@Transactional`, it will not work as expected, I guess.

How can I annotate the service class to create sub-transaction?

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/something")
@Transactional
public class SomeController {

    @Autowired
    private SomeService someService;

    @PostMapping("/endpoint")
    public void someEndpoint(@PathVariable final String id) {
        // do some work with service
    }
}

@Service
@Transactional(???)
public class SomeService {
    // some sub-transactional logic...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If those service need an indipendent transaction, simply annotate them with

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
```

Comment: And that's all? It's perfect. I knew there must be some annotation parameter to simply handle it. Thank you.

Comment: Keep in mind that for rollback purposes this is a new transaction.

Comment: Yes. That is exactly what I need.